# Changing the interval for alternating series test

Tags: calculus

Say I am doing an alternating series test, on a series from one to infinity, but after finding the first derivative of my sequence and drawing a number line, I find that it is only decreasing on the interval 2 to infinity. Would it be acceptable to say that the series has the same end behavior as a series from 2 to infinity, and continue with checking if the limit as n approaches infinity of that is 0? If I find that the second one is convergent, does that mean the first one must be?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are correct. If a series meets the conditions for the alternating series test after the 2nd term, then it converges. Indeed, even if a series meets these conditions only after the 10th, 100th, or 1,000th term, it still converges. The first $n$ terms of a series, no matter how large $n$ is (so long as $n$ is finite), do not affect the convergence of an infinite series.

Answer (score 1):

Not taking anything away from the other, correct answer.  It can help to see this:
$$  \sum_{i=1}^\infty f(i) = f(1) + \sum_{i=2}^\infty f(i)  $$
Let $(S_i)_{i=1}^\infty$ be the sequence of partial sums on the left and suppose $\lim_{i \rightarrow \infty} S_i = S$ exists.  The sum on the right has the sequence of partial sums $(S_i - f(1))_{i=2}^\infty$ and $\lim_{i \rightarrow \infty} (S_i - f(1)) = S-f(1)$, so the right-hand side gives $f(1) + (S - f(1)) = S$, just like the left-hand side.